# How to use JSON_TABLE with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Say a database column contains a json array like this:

```
[5,3,1]
```

I want to do a groupBy on the individual values of this column. I could achieve that by using a raw query:

```
DB::table(DB::raw('records, JSON_TABLE(records.column, "$[*]" COLUMNS(Value INT PATH "$")) AS data'))
    ->where('deleted_at', '=', null)
    ->where('user_id', '=', $this->user->id)
    ->selectRaw('data.Value')
    ->groupBy('data.Value')
    ->toSql()
```

which generates e.g.

```
select
    data.Value
from
    records,
    JSON_TABLE(
        records.column,
        "$[*]" COLUMNS(Value INT PATH "$")
    ) AS data
where
    `deleted_at` is null
    and `user_id` = 2
group by
    `data`.`Value`
```

My question is whether there is a more elegant way of achieving the same using eloquent.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast that field using a custom DTO or COllection object
like

```php
protected $casts = [
    'options' => AsCollection::class.':'.OptionCollection::class,
];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

or use as package as `spatie/laravel-data`

Comment: How does this help me with the query?